# Convert a date to words

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to convert a date value to words, so that i can be easily read.
i have the following code but i get  **A non well formed numeric value encountered (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\HRM\resources\views\admin.blade.php)** Error.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime($leaves->start);

$date2 = new DateTime($leaves->end);
$result = date('F jS Y', $leaves->start);
$results = date('F jS Y', $leaves->end);
?>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: What does `$leaves->start` and `$leaves->end` return?

Comment: @RushilPachchigar    i expect someting like 10th january 2017

Comment: @ObjectManipulator it returns  this format1/2/2017

Answer (score 0):

convert this first into valid date. Try this solution:

```
$result = date('jS F Y', strtotime($leaves->start));
$results = date('jS F Y', strtotime($leaves->end));
```

also remove following lines from your code:

```
$date = new DateTime($leaves->start);

$date2 = new DateTime($leaves->end);
```